# Composit component used to call one method from various beans

Tags: jsf

I need to call a method with same name dynamically from multiple beans, i have tried following composite code which works fine if passed without parameter but if parameter is passed the code does not work.

```
        <ui:composition> 
            <ui:param name="bean" value="#{managedBean}" />
            <ui:param name="method" value="MoveMainListPointer" />
            <o:methodParam name="methodfinal" value="#{bean[method]}" />
            <p:commandButton action="#{methodfinal}" value="Submit" />
            <br/>
        </ui:composition>
```

Following call is successful

```
<pc:PinnacleToolBar managedBean="#{BeanName1}" />
<pc:PinnacleToolBar managedBean="#{BeanName2}" />
<pc:PinnacleToolBar managedBean="#{BeanName3}" />
```

but as a parameter is passed,

```
        <ui:composition> 
            <ui:param name="bean" value="#{managedBean}" />
            <ui:param name="method" value="MoveMainListPointer('First')" />
            <o:methodParam name="methodfinal" value="#{bean[method]}" />
            <p:commandButton action="#{methodfinal}" value="Submit" />
            <br/>
        </ui:composition>
```

```
    public void MoveMainListPointer (MoveOptions M) {
        gu.MovePointer( this, M, listHeader, detTable, detTableHeaderNames, mainArray, detailArray );
    }
```

error

```
method not found
```

occurs.

Pls suggest.

Comment: The method is not found because you try to invoke `MoveMainListPointer(String)`. Initing the `MoveOptions` in the method by a string will fix this!

Comment: did you try already what i said in my previous comment? did it work? also methods begin with small case ([see java conventions](https://google.github.io/styleguide/javaguide.html#s5.1-identifier-names))

Comment: @fuggerjaki61 i couldnot understand what do u mean by "method by a string", what i m facing is that if the method has a parameter, then it cannot be passed as i hv mentioned above but if method does not hv a parameter it works f9, my actual problem is to make a set of around 16 buttons calling a same function from any bean name so i want to pass bean name dynamically in composit component or taglib and having method name fix with parameter.

Comment: `'some text'` is a string in el (expression language). you are trying to invoke `MoveMainListPointer(MoveOptions opts)` with this el expression `somebean.MoveMainListPointer('First')`. el thinks that it should call `MoveMainListPointer(String strg)` because `'some text'` is a string. Try to instantiate the `MoveOptions` by this string.

Comment: @fuggerjaki61 do u mean i should avoid having Parameter?? i m sorry i really cannot understand, pls give a short example, if possible, because if i don't hv a parameter i hv no problem already, the problem is with Parameter i.e. if i change the Parameter From (MoveOptions M) to (String M) even then the problem remain the same.  Furthermore, my actual requirement is to pass Method separate and having fix function call with parameter.

Comment: I will provide a solution later. Can you post the moveoptions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In EL (**E**xpression **L**anguage) you are calling the method like this:

```
someBean.MoveMainListPointer('First')
```

The method in the bean looks like this:

```
public void MoveMainListPointer (MoveOptions M) {...}
```

Now let's look at the parameter passed in EL: `'First'`. The text in single quotes is a String. You call the method with a String as parameter in EL and actually you want to call the method with some `MoveOptions` in the bean. You should notice that those are not the same (String is **not** `MoveOptions`). EL searches for a method with String as parameter which does not exist so the method can't be found.

**Solution**

As you want to set the parameter with a String change the method in the bean to following:

```
public void MoveMainListPointer(String strg) {
    // instantiate the MoveOptions here based on the string value
}
```

(Note: since the user hasn't put the code of `MoveOptions` I cannot provide how to do this.)

Also the convention for methods is that the first case is lower case ([see google conventions](https://google.github.io/styleguide/javaguide.html#s5.1-identifier-names)).

Comment: thanx it worked, i am posting the final solution as answer

Answer (score 1):

According to the solution posted by @fuggerjaki61, final code is as follows:-

```
    public static enum MoveOptions {
        Save,
        Edit,
        Clear,
        Delete,
        Check,
        Approve,
        First,
        Previous,
        Next,
        Last,
        Goto,
        Print,
        Copy,
        AdvanceSearch,
        Knocking
    }
```

```
    public void moveMainListPointer (String wToDo) {
        MoveOptions M = MoveOptions.valueOf(wToDo);
        System.out.println("Option: " + M);
        gu.MovePointer( this, M, listHeader, detTable, detTableHeaderNames, mainArray, detailArray );
    }
```

the Control

```
            <ui:param name="bean" value="#{managedBean}" />

            <o:methodParam name="MFS" value="#{bean.moveMainListPointer('Save')}" />
            <ui:param name="MFSB" value="#{bean.lockSaveButton}" />
            <p:commandButton id="btnSave" action="#{MFS}" value="Save" disabled="#{MFSB}"/>

            <o:methodParam name="MFS" value="#{bean.moveMainListPointer('Edit')}" />
            <p:commandButton id="btnEdit" action="#{MFS}" value="Edit" />
```

and finally the call

```
<pc:PinnacleToolBar managedBean="#{BeanName}" />
```